# Loadrunner replay scripting issue

Tags: testing, automation, warnings, loadrunner

Finding warning when I replay my recorded script using SSL2/3. 
It shows
1. No socket (out of 16 ) is currently available for a regular connection url .......
2. SSL protocol error when attrmpting to connect with host

The whole script is showing this , dono what is wrong. 
The web app contains images where I tried fiddler too but now the loadrunner is throwing this. 
Can anybody help to solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put this line at the beginning of your script:

```
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "<Set here your ssl version, see below>");
```

Accepted values are: '2', '3', '2&3', 'TLS', 'TLS1.1', or 'TLS1.2'

Example:

```
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS1.2");
```